# Error with pip install in Docker on Mac M1 when using Slim distribution of Python

Tags: python, docker, pip, apple-m1

I have an application I run on Docker which works fine on my older intel-based Mac.  However, on the M1 Mac, I get pip install errors when running docker-compose up. e.g

```
 asyncpg==0.24.0
 error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile uses python-slim which has no compiler, so I understand why:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /src
COPY . ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I'd like to stick to the -slim package. What is the best way to make this work on the Mac M1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and forcing the platform to `linux/amd64` fixed it:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.10-slim
```

See [known issues](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues):

> Not all images are available for ARM64 architecture. You can add `--platform linux/amd64` to run an Intel image under emulation.

Answer (score 4):

You can install missing packages like this on a Debian image. I've had the same issue in the past with the normal Postgres adapter.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
```

Make sure to put it before your pip install RUN directives.