# Can not Install Rust and Python Environment in Docker

Tags: docker, rust, cython, apache-arrow-datafusion

I am trying to install the package nautilus_trader (https://github.com/nautechsystems/nautilus_trader & https://docs.nautilustrader.io/getting_started/installation.html) in a docker container. However it always fails at compiling data fusion.

---

I am using a dev container setup in visual studio code

My dev container File:

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/docker-existing-dockerfile
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
    "build": {
        // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
        "context": "..",
        // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
        "dockerfile": "../dockerfile"
    },
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap",
                "ms-toolsai.jupyter",
                "GitHub.copilot",
                "njpwerner.autodocstring",
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"
            ]
        }
    }

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "cat /etc/os-release",

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    // "customizations": {},

    // Uncomment to connect as an existing user other than the container default. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "devcontainer"
}
```

My docker File:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim as base
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    BUILD_MODE="release"

ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:$POETRY_HOME/bin:$PATH"
ENV PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared"

FROM base as builder

# Install build deps
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl clang git openssh-client libssl-dev make pkg-config gcc python3-dev && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Rust stable 
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y

# install requirements from requirements.txt
# COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# set working directory
WORKDIR /workspace
```

---

It successfully creates the container.

However when running

```
pip install -U nautilus_trader
```

results in the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: nautilus_trader, psutil
  Building wheel for nautilus_trader (pyproject.toml) ... /^error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for nautilus_trader (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [721 lines of output]
      
      =====================================================================
      Nautilus Builder 1.179.0
      =====================================================================
      System: Linux aarch64
      Clang:  Debian clang version 14.0.6
      Rust:   1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
      Python: 3.11.6
      Cython: 3.0.4
      NumPy:  1.26.1
      
      BUILD_MODE=release
      BUILD_DIR=build/optimized
      PROFILE_MODE=False
      ANNOTATION_MODE=False
      PARALLEL_BUILD=True
      COPY_TO_SOURCE=True
      PYO3_ONLY=False
      
      Starting build...
      Compiling Rust libraries...
      cargo build --release --all-features
      info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu'
      info: latest update on 2023-11-02, rust version 1.75.0-nightly (75b064d26 2023-11-01)
      info: downloading component 'cargo'
      info: downloading component 'clippy'
      info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
      info: downloading component 'rust-std'
      info: downloading component 'rustc'
      info: downloading component 'rustfmt'
      info: installing component 'cargo'
      info: installing component 'clippy'
      info: installing component 'rust-docs'
      info: installing component 'rust-std'
      info: installing component 'rustc'
      info: installing component 'rustfmt'
          Updating crates.io index
          Updating git repository `https://github.com/anderslanglands/ustr`
          Updating git repository `https://github.com/snapview/tungstenite-rs`
       Downloading crates ...
         ** Download various packages **
         ** Compiling various packages **
         Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
         Compiling rand_chacha v0.3.1
         Compiling thrift v0.17.0
         Compiling object_store v0.7.1
         Compiling arrow-string v47.0.0
         Compiling brotli v3.4.0
         Compiling arrow-csv v47.0.0
         Compiling derive_builder_core v0.12.0
         Compiling arrow-json v47.0.0
         Compiling arrow-ord v47.0.0
         Compiling arrow-row v47.0.0
         Compiling arrow-arith v47.0.0
         Compiling twox-hash v1.6.3
         Compiling sqlparser_derive v0.1.1
         Compiling cpufeatures v0.2.10
         Compiling spin v0.5.2
         Compiling seq-macro v0.3.5
         Compiling untrusted v0.7.1
         Compiling sqlparser v0.38.0
         Compiling arrow v47.0.0
         Compiling derive_builder_macro v0.12.0
         Compiling tabled_derive v0.6.0
         Compiling nautilus-model v0.10.0 (/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/model)
         Compiling uuid v1.5.0
         Compiling openssl v0.10.57
         Compiling foreign-types-shared v0.1.1
         Compiling foreign-types v0.3.2
         Compiling rust_decimal_macros v1.32.0
         Compiling openssl-macros v0.1.1
         Compiling blake3 v1.5.0
         Compiling native-tls v0.2.11
         Compiling openssl-probe v0.1.5
         Compiling httparse v1.8.0
         Compiling http v0.2.9
         Compiling rmp v0.8.12
         Compiling lzma-sys v0.1.20
         Compiling bzip2-sys v0.1.11+1.0.8
         Compiling rustls v0.21.7
         Compiling constant_time_eq v0.3.0
         Compiling arrayref v0.3.7
         Compiling zstd-safe v7.0.0
         Compiling fixedbitset v0.4.2
         Compiling petgraph v0.6.4
         Compiling rmp-serde v1.1.2
         Compiling sct v0.7.0
         Compiling rustls-webpki v0.101.6
         Compiling sha2 v0.10.8
         Compiling md-5 v0.10.6
         Compiling blake2 v0.10.6
         Compiling ustr v0.10.0 (https://github.com/anderslanglands/ustr#c78ddc25)
         Compiling dashmap v5.5.3
         Compiling bytecount v0.6.4
         Compiling hex v0.4.3
         Compiling unicode-segmentation v1.10.1
         Compiling papergrid v0.9.1
         Compiling nautilus-common v0.10.0 (/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/common)
         Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.8.16
         Compiling regex-syntax v0.6.29
         Compiling try-lock v0.2.4
         Compiling regex-automata v0.1.10
         Compiling want v0.3.1
         Compiling tabled v0.12.2
         Compiling http-body v0.4.5
         Compiling derive_builder v0.12.0
         Compiling rustls-webpki v0.100.3
         Compiling sha1 v0.10.6
         Compiling rustls-pemfile v1.0.3
         Compiling socket2 v0.4.10
         Compiling httpdate v1.0.3
         Compiling thousands v0.2.0
         Compiling powerfmt v0.2.0
         Compiling evalexpr v11.1.0
         Compiling utf-8 v0.7.6
         Compiling overload v0.1.1
         Compiling tower-service v0.3.2
         Compiling data-encoding v2.4.0
         Compiling hyper v0.14.27
         Compiling nu-ansi-term v0.46.0
         Compiling deranged v0.3.9
         Compiling webpki-roots v0.23.1
         Compiling rustls-native-certs v0.6.3
         Compiling matchers v0.1.0
         Compiling tokio-rustls v0.24.1
         Compiling tokio-util v0.7.9
         Compiling tracing-log v0.1.3
         Compiling sharded-slab v0.1.7
         Compiling pyo3-asyncio-macros v0.19.0
         Compiling thread_local v1.1.7
         Compiling glob v0.3.1
         Compiling time-core v0.1.2
         Compiling compare v0.1.0
         Compiling binary-heap-plus v0.5.0
         Compiling time v0.3.30
         Compiling tracing-subscriber v0.3.17
         Compiling pyo3-asyncio v0.19.0
         Compiling crossbeam-channel v0.5.8
         Compiling nautilus-backtest v0.10.0 (/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/backtest)
         Compiling nonzero_ext v0.3.0
         Compiling tracing-appender v0.2.2
         Compiling bzip2 v0.4.4
         Compiling lz4 v1.24.0
         Compiling zstd v0.12.4
         Compiling zstd v0.13.0
         Compiling parquet v47.0.0
         Compiling xz2 v0.1.7
         Compiling async-compression v0.4.4
         Compiling datafusion-common v32.0.0
         Compiling datafusion-expr v32.0.0
         Compiling datafusion-physical-expr v32.0.0
         Compiling datafusion-execution v32.0.0
         Compiling datafusion-sql v32.0.0
         Compiling tokio-native-tls v0.3.1
         Compiling tungstenite v0.20.1 (https://github.com/snapview/tungstenite-rs#8b3ecd3c)
         Compiling hyper-tls v0.5.0
         Compiling tokio-tungstenite v0.19.0 (/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/network/tokio-tungstenite)
         Compiling datafusion-optimizer v32.0.0
         Compiling datafusion-physical-plan v32.0.0
         Compiling nautilus-network v0.10.0 (/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/network)
         Compiling datafusion v32.0.0
      error: could not compile `parquet` (lib)
      
      Caused by:
        process didn't exit successfully: `/root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name parquet --edition=2021 /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/parquet-47.0.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C panic=abort -C codegen-units=1 --cfg 'feature="arrow"' --cfg 'feature="arrow-array"' --cfg 'feature="arrow-buffer"' --cfg 'feature="arrow-cast"' --cfg 'feature="arrow-data"' --cfg 'feature="arrow-ipc"' --cfg 'feature="arrow-schema"' --cfg 'feature="arrow-select"' --cfg 'feature="async"' --cfg 'feature="base64"' --cfg 'feature="brotli"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="flate2"' --cfg 'feature="futures"' --cfg 'feature="lz4"' --cfg 'feature="object_store"' --cfg 'feature="snap"' --cfg 'feature="tokio"' --cfg 'feature="zstd"' -C metadata=732a882532a44912 -C extra-filename=-732a882532a44912 --out-dir /tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps -C strip=symbols -L dependency=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps --extern ahash=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libahash-f8c7e181ec531570.rmeta --extern arrow_array=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_array-391b751877378487.rmeta --extern arrow_buffer=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_buffer-4c2dc118f28f9830.rmeta --extern arrow_cast=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_cast-e3651f97941bb398.rmeta --extern arrow_data=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_data-ffec4b4d68adfe46.rmeta --extern arrow_ipc=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_ipc-3c7cd6bfdf394632.rmeta --extern arrow_schema=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_schema-66e81e2106597b2b.rmeta --extern arrow_select=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_select-7e089b3f91c42157.rmeta --extern base64=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libbase64-2e3db9966e70dada.rmeta --extern brotli=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libbrotli-bc16e04d11798417.rmeta --extern bytes=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libbytes-cf462e343a7efd20.rmeta --extern chrono=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libchrono-e76497d77660c6fb.rmeta --extern flate2=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libflate2-ebe1a782e431604d.rmeta --extern futures=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libfutures-52698374686e6a1c.rmeta --extern hashbrown=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libhashbrown-e37b74be31fd9681.rmeta --extern lz4=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/liblz4-f8ac8e02131c2456.rmeta --extern num=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libnum-a636535aa738e27f.rmeta --extern num_bigint=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libnum_bigint-2e83c170636fea6d.rmeta --extern object_store=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libobject_store-dac970a11e38b020.rmeta --extern paste=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libpaste-2c291736c09ae1f3.so --extern seq_macro=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libseq_macro-3bf6615f31e71763.so --extern snap=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libsnap-20be7abf350a600d.rmeta --extern thrift=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libthrift-fe02920cff57b0ba.rmeta --extern tokio=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libtokio-5532a7fed261ab11.rmeta --extern twox_hash=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libtwox_hash-be7d80bbaf3358ab.rmeta --extern zstd=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libzstd-18e8d487e3626f92.rmeta --cap-lints allow '-Aclippy::drop_non_drop' -L native=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/build/lz4-sys-da126b84bb35ea50/out -L native=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/build/zstd-sys-c268c5a67360357f/out` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
      warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
      error: could not compile `datafusion-physical-expr` (lib)
      
      Caused by:
        process didn't exit successfully: `/root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name datafusion_physical_expr --edition=2021 /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/datafusion-physical-expr-32.0.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C panic=abort -C codegen-units=1 --cfg 'feature="base64"' --cfg 'feature="blake2"' --cfg 'feature="blake3"' --cfg 'feature="crypto_expressions"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="encoding_expressions"' --cfg 'feature="hex"' --cfg 'feature="md-5"' --cfg 'feature="regex"' --cfg 'feature="regex_expressions"' --cfg 'feature="sha2"' --cfg 'feature="unicode-segmentation"' --cfg 'feature="unicode_expressions"' -C metadata=d75827de064fcc86 -C extra-filename=-d75827de064fcc86 --out-dir /tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps -C strip=symbols -L dependency=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps --extern ahash=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libahash-f8c7e181ec531570.rmeta --extern arrow=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow-0e2d1cea6856de05.rmeta --extern arrow_array=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_array-391b751877378487.rmeta --extern arrow_buffer=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_buffer-4c2dc118f28f9830.rmeta --extern arrow_schema=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libarrow_schema-66e81e2106597b2b.rmeta --extern base64=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libbase64-2e3db9966e70dada.rmeta --extern blake2=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libblake2-3de0823269d97639.rmeta --extern blake3=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libblake3-66d079205f8d1ac4.rmeta --extern chrono=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libchrono-e76497d77660c6fb.rmeta --extern datafusion_common=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libdatafusion_common-9b25e7aa02b0e689.rmeta --extern datafusion_expr=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libdatafusion_expr-d40df74bb09b4495.rmeta --extern half=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libhalf-c94cfd11d1b0b977.rmeta --extern hashbrown=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libhashbrown-e37b74be31fd9681.rmeta --extern hex=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libhex-0cfcc65bfb9e14c1.rmeta --extern indexmap=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libindexmap-4ce0b8e6517f109f.rmeta --extern itertools=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libitertools-394413f0bd459b6d.rmeta --extern libc=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/liblibc-39537ece03a37e4f.rmeta --extern log=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/liblog-5d9f4f403d0578b4.rmeta --extern md5=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libmd5-5fbffd3035165d47.rmeta --extern paste=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libpaste-2c291736c09ae1f3.so --extern petgraph=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libpetgraph-6615ffef5850fa07.rmeta --extern rand=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/librand-b3c4d5d75d08e2d0.rmeta --extern regex=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libregex-de18c839e12efdeb.rmeta --extern sha2=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libsha2-a1e6fb9e92d194de.rmeta --extern unicode_segmentation=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libunicode_segmentation-65a8986ee38e3092.rmeta --extern uuid=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/deps/libuuid-66b93dc7acac5cf2.rmeta --cap-lints allow '-Aclippy::drop_non_drop' -L native=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/build/blake3-e411be9361602c0f/out -L native=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/build/lz4-sys-da126b84bb35ea50/out -L native=/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/nautilus_core/target/release/build/zstd-sys-c268c5a67360357f/out` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/build.py", line 100, in _build_rust_libs
          subprocess.run(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cargo', 'build', '--release', '--all-features']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
      
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/build.py", line 354, in <module>
          build()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/build.py", line 307, in build
          _build_rust_libs()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jmgbdbj5/nautilus-trader_36ee0ae5551b47ea93ea30b413802ebe/build.py", line 106, in _build_rust_libs
          raise RuntimeError(
      RuntimeError: Error running cargo: Command '['cargo', 'build', '--release', '--all-features']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_6sya1uv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/api.py", line 58, in build_wheel
          return WheelBuilder.make_in(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_6sya1uv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 88, in make_in
          wb.build(target_dir=directory)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_6sya1uv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 123, in build
          self._build(zip_file)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_6sya1uv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 172, in _build
          self._run_build_script(self._package.build_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_6sya1uv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 266, in _run_build_script
          subprocess.check_call([self.executable.as_posix(), build_script])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', 'build.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for nautilus_trader
  Building wheel for psutil (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for psutil: filename=psutil-5.9.6-cp311-abi3-linux_aarch64.whl size=285307 sha256=1001ab380522c05286bb4070128da10f19009610f9c22a4537fd93c83478149e
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-nqhe0y4s/wheels/e7/d5/c0/20823c8375fdfa97fe0aea4f718185c7d07e9aee188577bee6
Successfully built psutil
Failed to build nautilus_trader
ERROR: Could not build wheels for nautilus_trader, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am Using MacOS14.1 M1 chip and Docker Desktop 4.25.0

Edit: Some friends on mine can execute the commands without errors (Also Mac, but not with M1 chip - however that's why we use docker...)

Had to Edit to Logging Output for Stack overflow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you build a crate on its own in the container? We can't see why `cargo` is failing in the given output.

Comment: Updated the question and tried to provide the full logging output. Just skipped a few lines containing "downloaded xxx btw. compiled xxx"

Comment: The build for your pip wheel has failed for some reason which is not included in the logs. You can try going into your docker container and running the command manually to get more details. Anyway, it's probably a problem with your package build command. Maybe incompatibility with the latest version of Rust. You can blindly change the version or switch to another toolchain channel to see if the problem gets fixed.

Comment: Can you please be more specific which command to run? I also checked that data fusion should be compatible with the latest rust version (https://crates.io/crates/datafusion-optimizer).

Comment: Note that Docker is *not* going to help if the problem is with compatibility between Rust and M1.

Also, it looks like `pip install -U nautilus_trader` is reinstalling Rust. That's a bit surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

Edited

```
FROM python:3.11-slim
```

to

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.11-slim
```

in my docker file.

Solution from:
[Error with pip install in Docker on Mac M1 when using Slim distribution of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281306/error-with-pip-install-in-docker-on-mac-m1-when-using-slim-distribution-of-pytho)